# Prove that $\mathbb{P}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}\geq \epsilon u^2/2) \geq 1-2e^{-c\epsilon n}$ given $\mathbb{P}(X_i^2 \geq u^2) \geq \epsilon$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

> Assume that $\mathbb{P}(X_i^2 \geq u^2) \geq \epsilon$ and $X_i$ are i.i.d. Prove that $\mathbb{P}(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}\geq \epsilon u^2/2) \geq 1-2e^{-c\epsilon n}$ for all $c > 0$.

Can anyone give me some hints? It sounds related to central limit theorem but I am not sure how.

Comment: Maybe the Paley-Zygmund inequality is not a bad idea? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality)

Comment: @cptflint I am not sure it will work because we have the exponential here.

Comment: I think, there is something better! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound

I'll post a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: Mhhh, so maybe there is one point missing. I would say, we use Chernoff. So $X:= \sum^n X_i$ and $P( X\leq a) \leq \min\limits_{t> 0} e^{ t a}  \prod_i E[ \exp( -t X_i) ] \leq e^{ c a}  \prod_i E[ \exp( -c X_i) ] $ for any $c>0$. So we get $P(X>a) \geq 1- e^{c a} E[ \exp(-c X_i)]^n$. For $a:= n\varepsilon u^2/2 $ this gives us $1-\exp( c\varepsilon n u^2 /2 ) E[ \exp(-c X_i)]^n$. And with $P( X_i^2 \geq u^2 ) \geq \varepsilon^2$ it could be possible to make the last step?

Comment: @cptflint I am not sure that $E[exp(-cX_i^2)] \leq exp(-c\epsilon u^2)$ is true or not. I do know that $E(X_i^2) \geq u^2 \epsilon$.